# WordPress plugin write out of www folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a Wordpress plugin which manages a specific form. I would need to copy information retrieved from the input of customer in a folder which is not in the www folder (where Wordpress is installed).

My server file structure is the following:

- ./datas
- ./www
- ./www/wp-admin
- ./www/wp-content
- ./www/wp-content/plugins/myplugin
- ./www/wp-includes

My plugin (stored in the myplugin folder) would need to create, for each new form received, a new folder into datas folder (located at the same level of www folder) and create a text file containing the input information.

any idea on how I can do that (if this is possible of course)?

Comment: Use absolute path. But it security reasons I do not recommend this.

Comment: Agree with @Dmitry. You can achieve these using absolute paths. But it's a security issue to make your app write outside of its folder. Why do you want to store it outside your WP?

Comment: because another script independent from WP is managing this external folder...

Comment: another script can reach plugin's folder as well, isn't it? This is more secure than saving outside www folder

Comment: you're right, I'll do like that